# Ряд назывных предложений, а затем обобщение

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, запятые, сложное-предложение, именительный-темы

*Доклады на конференциях, участие в бизнес-форумах, проведение презентаций перед потенциальными клиентами и партнёрами на работе[,] — выступать перед аудиторией приходится довольно часто.*

С одной стороны, можно провести аналогию с однородными членами и обобщающим словом, стоящим после них, и поставить тире. С другой — можно трактовать последнее предложение как присоединительное с дополнительным значением и поставить запятую и тире как единый знак.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Доклады на конференциях, участие в бизнес-форумах, проведение презентаций перед потенциальными клиентами и партнёрами на работе — **выступать перед аудиторией приходится довольно часто.**

Это не назывные предложения, а номинативы. Подробно они рассмотрены в следующем источнике https://studfiles.net/preview/2682296/

Этот тип номинативов можно отнести **к изолированным номинативам в препозиции.** В ПАС они рассматриваются **в качестве именительного темы**

Для постановки тире в таких предложениях требуется **слово-отсылка.** В нашем случае формально его нет, но оно подразумевается.  Сравнить: Доклады на конференциях, участие в бизнес-форумах, проведение презентаций перед потенциальными клиентами и партнёрами на работе — выступать перед  аудиторией **в таких случаях** приходится довольно часто.

Правило http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=110#pp110

Однако **при именительном темы**, более тесно связанном с основным предложением, в котором имеется личное или указательное местоимение **в качестве слова-отсылки,** ставится тире: Тягач — он как танк, только без башни (газ.); Марченко — тот был человек, золотой человек (Каз.);

Comment: Не спешите. Это не именительные темы. Предложения в первой части не перечисляют вещи, о которых будет говориться во второй. У этих предложений есть свой смысл. _Я рассказываю доклады на конференциях, я участвую в бизнес-форумах, я провожу презентации перед потенциальными клиентами и партнёрами на работе[,] — выступать перед аудиторией приходится довольно часто._ Так что в первой части не темы, а законченные мысли, выраженные назывными предложениями.

Comment: Не спешите? Не могу понять смысл Вашей фразы. Я привела Вам ссылку на статью, в которой говорится о том, чем номинативы отличаются от назывных предложений. Пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с ней. Например: "Разграничение номинативных предложений и схожих по форме конструкций представляется возможным при учете такого свойства предложения, как самостоятельность функционирования". Ваши назывные конструкции не являются функционально независимыми, а это признак того, что это структурные элементы в составе предложения.

Comment: Если Вы переходите к двусоставным предложениям (я выступаю с докладами на конференции и т.д), то тогда это другая грамматика и другие знаки препинания. И соответственно, совсем другой вопрос. Существует такое понятие,  как синтаксическая синонимия. Это означает, что одно и то же содержание может иметь разную грамматическую форму. И анализировать надо именно ту форму, которую Вы выбрали.

Comment: Конечно, я ознакомился с указанной Вами статьёй и различаю новинативы и назывные предложения. Почему мои назывные предложения не являются функционально независимыми? По смыслу они не зависят от последующего предложения. Они выражают самостоятельные мысли, что я продемонстрировал вам, переведя их в синонимичные двусоставные.

Comment: А Вы попробуйте быть моим оппонентом до конца. Докажите, что я ошибаюсь и что это назывные предложения. Я не считаю, что в Вашем случае набор назывных форм  имеет такой статус.

Comment: По‑моему, в первом комментарии я дал достаточную аргументацию. Возникает впечатление, что вы не прочитали его полностью, а остановились на "Не спешите". Впрочем извиняюсь, если излишне непринуждённо выразился, — я лишь хотел указать, что вы слишком поспешно увидели здесь именительные темы, тогда как семантика и функция этих назывных форм другая.

Comment: У нас есть определенные трудности в общении, которое на форуме должно происходить в формате "вопрос-ответ". Я отвечаю, Вы можете что-то спросить или уточнить в комментарии, а потом просто принять к сведению.  Правильность ответа обсуждается другими участниками форума, но не участником, задающим вопрос. Вы же предлагаете мне общение в виде дискуссии, а это не совсем корректно. (Я высказываю свое мнение, а Вы сомневаетесь в его правильности).

Comment: Ожидаемым был бы такой корректный вопрос-уточнение: А почему вы думаете, что это не назывные предложения?  И корректный (нераспространенный) ответ: Это следует из определения и классификации назывных предложений. Вот с этого и надо начинать что-либо доказывать, а Вы пока что убедили себя, а не меня в достаточности Вашей аргументации.

Comment: Я изучил материалы по номинативам. Соглашусь, здесь нет констатации бытия предмета, явления. Вы правы. Однако вставленное Вами **в таких случаях** в последнем предложении, которое якобы подразумевается, совсем не соответствует задуманному смыслу. Задуманный смысл следующий: обозначаемые номинативами события в совокупности являются иллюстрацией того, что выступать приходится часто. Смысл не в том, что именно в таких ситуациях приходится часто выступать. Кстати, не понравился вариант с двоеточием от **slava1947**.

Comment: Можно сказать: в названных случаях.  Просто этот ряд номинативов надо как-то связать со второй частью предложения, чтобы обосновать постановку тире. При постановке многоточия эта тесная связь не обозначена, а сделать это необходимо.

Comment: 1) Если **в названных случаях**, то грамматически так же получаем неправильную семантику: приходится часто выступать на конференциях, приходится часто участвовать в бизнес-форумах и приходится часто делать презентации. А это не то, что задумывалось. 2) Так если ставить многоточие, то необходимость связывать отпадает.

Comment: Тогда оформите так, как считаете нужным. Вы получили достаточно информации по теме. Я вижу предложение, понимаю его содержание, и этого достаточно, чтобы предложить Вам оптимальный вариант (с моей точки зрения).

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант:

***Доклады на конференциях, участие в бизнес-форумах, проведение презентаций перед потенциальными клиентами и партнёрами на работе... Выступать перед аудиторией приходится довольно часто.***